# Opening a terminal on Eee PC

Tags: installation, eeepc

I have an Eee PC 1005PEB that I want to install Ubuntu on. I've tried hitting <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> on the Express gate screen but nothing happens. I've also tried to boot from a live CD on a usb, but nothing seems to work, I've tried it on the left & the right side ports.

I'm not too experienced with Linux, but I've been using it on my HP Pavilion for a couple of months. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: To install Ubuntu, you need to boot from the installation media (CD/USB) and not try opening a terminal. Do you get any error when booting from USB?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think opening a terminal will do much good if you haven't installed Ubuntu yet.  You want to get to the BIOS menu; I don't know what it is on the Eee PC, but often you must press F2 or F12 while it boots up.  The correct key is probably in a manual somewhere or displayed on screen.  You want to choose to boot from the USB.  Then you can install Ubuntu and use a terminal to your heart's content.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issues as I needed to resurrect an old EEE PC 1000.  The only way around this problem, I found, was to ignore terminal and install from a DVD.  The BIOS settings key at startup is F2.  Set the DVD drive as primary startup.  Also try LUBUNTU instead of UBUNTU on older EEE PCs, it works much better.